# two xml requests in c# wpf application

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm needing to put two xml requests into one wpf c# application. Originally, I needed only one request, but due to a constraint, I need two xml requests. I can get it working by removing the first xml script and replacing it with the second, however, I need the wpf xaml class to run one request, then move onto the other, after the first one is ran.

I'm wondering if I need a second xaml.cs to run after the first xaml.cs is ran. If I were to do this, how would I instruct the first xaml.cs to execute, then, immediateky run the second xaml.cs after the first one has ran?

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Here's my code:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office.CustomUI;
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        static readonly HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //by adding the following line of code, this application will run un-atended.
            //to enable window with Submit button, uncomment the following line of code. 
            Button_Click(null, null);
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string accountName = "accountName";
            string userName = "userName";
            string password = "password";
            string key = "asdfg";

            // Query the DB
            // SELECT DISTINCT TranNum FROM Invoice_View
            // List<string> orderNumbers
            // foreach(orderNumber in orderNumbers){

            // Get the invoice records from the database
            List<DBInvoiceModel> invoiceRecords = GetInvoiceRecords(100);

            // Calculate the XML request and send it
            string UpdateOrderXML = await UpdateOrder(accountName, password, userName, invoiceRecords);
            //string ordersXML = await QueryOrders(key, accountName);  
            //}
        }

        //the following query is taken from a view of data: "Invoice_View"
        private List<DBInvoiceModel> GetInvoiceRecords(int orderNumber)
        {
            // "Invoice_View"
            var dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=database;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true");
            dbConnection.Open();
            var sqlCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT
                      [ItemID]
                      ,[TranNo]  
                      ,[STaxAmt]
                      ,[TranAmt]
                      ,[Status]
                      ,[TranNum]
                      ,[QtyShipped]
                      ,[FreightAmt]
                      ,[TrackingNumber]
                      ,[ItemPrice]
                   FROM [Test].[dbo].[Invoices]
                      WHERE TranNum = '" + orderNumber.ToString() + "'";

            var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<DBInvoiceModel> result = new List<DBInvoiceModel>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                //converting the columns returned to strings.
                DBInvoiceModel invoiceRecord = new DBInvoiceModel
                {
                    //order no?
                    ItemID = reader[0].ToString(),//2-3
                    //suppress leading zeros
                    TranNo = reader[1].ToString().TrimStart('0'), //4
                    ///log

                    STaxAmt = Convert.ToDouble(reader[2]),//5
                    TranAmt = Convert.ToDouble(reader[3]),//calculation
                    Status = Convert.ToInt32(reader[4]),//6
                    EDITranNum = reader[5].ToString(),//calculation
                    //log
                    QtyShipped = Convert.ToInt32(reader[6]),//7
                    FreightAmt = Convert.ToDouble(reader[7]),//8
                    TrackingNumber = reader[8].ToString(),//9
                    ItemPrice = Convert.ToDouble(reader[9])//calculation

            };
                Log2DB(invoiceRecord.TranNum, invoiceRecord.TranNo); 
                result.Add(invoiceRecord);
            }
            reader.Close();
            sqlCmd.Dispose();
            dbConnection.Close();
            return result;

        }

        public void Log2DB(string TranNum, string TranNo)
        {
            Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            logger.Info("invoice");
        }



        //sending the update        
        private async Task<string> QueryOrders(string key, string accountName)
        {
            string XMLstring = CalculateOrderQueryXML(key, accountName);
            StringContent stringcontent = new StringContent(XMLstring);

            stringcontent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "text/XML";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.PostAsync("https://www.example.com/shared/xml/orderquery.rest", stringcontent);

            /*string for response*/
            string ResponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(ResponseString);

            return xml.OuterXml;

        }

        private string CalculateOrderQueryXML(string key, string accountName)
        {
            //TODO: MAKE THE APPLICATION WORK THRU ALL ORDERS NOT SPECIFY A RANGE
            int OrderNoStart = 100;
            int OrderNoEnd = 200;
            string XMLstring = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                <OrderQueryRequest>
                  <Credentials>
                    <AccountName>{0}</AccountName>
                    <Key>{1}</Key>
                  </Credentials>
                  <OrderNoRange>
                    <OrderNoStart>{2}</OrderNoStart>
                    <OrderNoEnd>{3}</OrderNoEnd>
                  </OrderNoRange>
                  <Page>1</Page>
                </OrderQueryRequest>
                 ";

            XMLstring = string.Format(XMLstring, accountName, key, OrderNoStart, OrderNoEnd);
            return XMLstring;
        }


        private async Task<string> UpdateOrder(string accountName, string password, string userName, List<DBInvoiceModel> invoiceRecords)
        {
            string XMLstring = UpdateOrderXML(accountName, password, userName, invoiceRecords);
            StringContent stringcontent = new StringContent(XMLstring);
            stringcontent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "text/XML";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.PostAsync("https://www.example.com/shared/xml/orderupdate.rest", stringcontent);

            /*string for response*/
            string ResponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(ResponseString);
            return xml.OuterXml;

        }

        private string UpdateOrderXML(string accountName, string password, string userName, List<DBInvoiceModel> invoiceRecords)
        {

            double transactionTotal = 0;
            double salesTaxTotalAmt = 0;
            double dropShipFee = 0;
            double processingFee = 0;
            string OrderNumber = "";
            string InvoiceNumber = "";

            foreach (var invoiceRecord in invoiceRecords)
            {
                EDIOrderNumber = invoiceRecord.EDITranNum;
                InvoiceNumber = invoiceRecord.TranNo;

                if (invoiceRecord.ItemID == "PROCESSING FEE")
                {
                    processingFee = invoiceRecord.ItemPrice;
                }
                else if (invoiceRecord.ItemID == "DROP SHIP FEE")
                {
                    dropShipFee = invoiceRecord.ItemPrice;
                }
                else
                {
                    transactionTotal = transactionTotal + invoiceRecord.ItemPrice;
                }


                salesTaxTotalAmt = salesTaxTotalAmt + invoiceRecord.STaxAmt;
            }
            double salesTaxRate = salesTaxTotalAmt / transactionTotal;

            //formatted XML -- second request
            //string XMLstring = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
            //       <OrderUpdateRequest>  
            //        <Credentials>  
            //          <AccountName>{0}</AccountName>  
            //          <UserName>{1}</UserName>  
            //          <Password>{2}</Password>  
            //        </Credentials>
            //          <OrderUpdate>
            //            <OrderNo>{3}</OrderNo>  


            //         <StatusUpdate>

            //               <Status>Shipped</Status> 
            //               <TrackingNumber>1234567890</TrackingNumber>  

            //        </StatusUpdate>



            //          <BillingStatusUpdate>
            //            <BillingStatus>Billed</BillingStatus>
            //          </BillingStatusUpdate>

            //           <LineItemAdd> 
            //     <Product>
            //                    <Qty>1</Qty>
            //     <ProductNo>200</ProductNo> 
            //    </Product>


            //            </LineItemAdd>

            //          </OrderUpdate>      
            //        </OrderUpdateRequest>
            //   "; 

            //formatted XML -- first request
            string XMLstring = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                       <OrderUpdateRequest>  
                        <Credentials>  
                          <AccountName>{0}</AccountName>  
                          <UserName>{1}</UserName>  
                          <Password>{2}</Password>  
                        </Credentials>
                          <OrderUpdate>
                            <OrderNo>{3}</OrderNo>  
                            <CommentsUpdate>
                                <CustomerComments>Invoice Number {4}</CustomerComments>
                            </CommentsUpdate>
                            <SalesTaxUpdate>
                                <SalesTaxRate>
                                {5}
                                </SalesTaxRate>
                            </SalesTaxUpdate>
                              <ShippingOptionsUpdate>
                             <ShipRate>10</ShipRate> 
                         </ShippingOptionsUpdate>

                         <StatusUpdate>

                               <Status>Shipped</Status> 
                               <TrackingNumber>1234567890</TrackingNumber>  

                        </StatusUpdate>

                           <LineItemUpdate>
                                <Qty>1</Qty> 
                            </LineItemUpdate>

                          <BillingStatusUpdate>
                            <BillingStatus>Billed</BillingStatus>
                          </BillingStatusUpdate>

                           <LineItemAdd> 
                                 <Product>
                                    <Qty>1</Qty>
                                    <ProductNo>100</ProductNo> 
                                </Product>


                            </LineItemAdd>

                          </OrderUpdate>      
                        </OrderUpdateRequest>
                   ";


            XMLstring = string.Format(XMLstring, accountName, userName, password, OrderNumber, InvoiceNumber, salesTaxRate, dropShipFee, processingFee);
            return XMLstring;
        }

    }
}
```

the second xml request uses the same methods and variables as the first request, however, it is shorter:

```
            //formatted XML -- second request
            string XMLstring = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
            <OrderUpdateRequest>
                    <Credentials>
                      <AccountName>{0}</AccountName>   
                      <UserName>{1}</UserName>      
                      <Password>{2}</Password>         
                    </Credentials>         
                       <OrderUpdate>         
                       <OrderNo>{3}</OrderNo> 
                            <StatusUpdate>
                               <Status>Shipped</Status>
                               <TrackingNumber>1234567890</TrackingNumber>
                            </StatusUpdate>
                            <BillingStatusUpdate>
                               <BillingStatus>Billed</BillingStatus>
                            </BillingStatusUpdate>
                            <LineItemAdd>
                               <Product>
                                 <Qty>1</Qty>
                                 <ProductNo>300</ProductNo>
                               </Product>
                            </LineItemAdd>
                        </OrderUpdate>
                    </OrderUpdateRequest>
                           ";
```

Comment: Not sure I get the problem. Can't you just run the second request after the first? Or run them in parallel? What is the issue?

Comment: There seems to be confusion over a `xaml file` and an `xml request` here. While both are in the realm of programming they are not related. There's no reason a second `xml request` would require a second `xaml file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need another .xaml.cs implementation to do two things back-to-back.  Your MainWindow.xaml.cs contains a Button_Click method that performs the first request, correct?  Why can't you just piggy back off of it to do your second request immediately after the first one has ran?

Example:

```
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                // ... some code removed for brevity

                // Get the invoice records from the database
                List<DBInvoiceModel> invoiceRecords = GetInvoiceRecords(123456);

                // Define your first and seocnd xml string requests here
                string xmlReq1 = "blah blah blah";
                string xmlReq2 = "blah blah blah blah";

                // Calculate the 1st XML request and send it
                string UpdateOrderXML1 = await UpdateOrder(accountName, password, userName, invoiceRecords, xmlReq1);

                // Calculate the 2nd XML request and send it
                string UpdateOrderXML2 = await UpdateOrder(accountName, password, userName, invoiceRecords, xmlReq2);

        }
```

Then edit your methods to take in the xml string as a parameter:

```
        private async Task<string> UpdateOrder(string accountName, string password, string userName, List<DBInvoiceModel> invoiceRecords, string xmlRequestString)
        {
            string XMLstring = UpdateOrderXML(accountName, password, userName, invoiceRecords, xmlRequestString);
            ...
        }

        private string UpdateOrderXML(string accountName, string password, string userName, List<DBInvoiceModel> invoiceRecords, string xmlRequestString)
        {
            ...

            foreach (var invoiceRecord in invoiceRecords)
            {
              ...
            }
            double salesTaxRate = salesTaxTotalAmt / transactionTotal;

            // REMOVE ALL YOUR OLD xmlString code HERE

            return string.Format(xmlRequestString, accountName, userName, password, OrderNumber, InvoiceNumber, salesTaxRate, dropShipFee, processingFee);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you....I will try this.....I will try tomorrow and get back to you, ok?

Comment: I wonder, is it possible to create a second xaml.cs file and have it execute after the first one is finished?

Comment: When you say you want a second xaml.cs file, to me it implies you are creating a new xaml file as well.  A xaml.cs is called a "code-behind" file for a xaml file.  Creating a standalone xaml.cs file doesn't makes sense.  Also, whatever code you are putting in the xaml.cs file can probably be easily placed within the existing xaml.cs file.  It would be helpful if you included all of your files for me to see (including the xaml file), and please point out what is the 2nd request you are trying to run. Without seeing the full picture, all I'm doing is guessing what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can force the application to run by replacing the xml requests, one after the other. I put the contents of MainWindow.xaml.cs in the first code, followed by the second xml request, just in well-formed xml.

Comment: Michele, it looks to me as if you have have embeded your 1st and 2nd xml requests too deep into your UpdateOrder and UpdateOrderXML methods.  You should define both of those requests OUTSIDE of your methods, then you can pass this inside as a parameter.  See my updated answer text.

Comment: thank you. I will try this to see if I can resolve as per your suggestions.